# install opencv 3.1.0

Tags: software-installation, opencv, kinect

I downloaded opencv3.1.0 and extracted it then I opened cmake and built it.Then I opened terminal and in its directory (the directory of given to cmake as build address) typed "make".when making is completed I typed "make install" but an error occured below:

```
[100%] Built target opencv_traincascade
[100%] Built target opencv_createsamples
[100%] Built target opencv_annotation
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib.  Maybe
  need administrative privileges.

make: *** [install] Error 1
```

what is the problem?
thank you

Comment: You should do `sudo make install` not `make install`

Answer (score 4):

`make install` doesn't work here because the installer needs access to `/usr` which is a system directory. So you will have to do `sudo make install`